# How to Generate Spritesheet from a 'problematic' animated Symbol in Flash Pro CS6?

Tags: animation, flash, actionscript-3, spritesheet

In the new Flash Pro CS6 there is an option to generate spriteheet from a symbol. I used these tutorials:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/using-sprite-sheet-generator.html

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs6-creative-cloud-feature-tour-for-web/generating-sprite-sheets-using-flash-professional-cs6/

And it works really well!

An artist I'm working with created a bunch of assets for a game. One of them is a walking person as seen from a top-down view.

You can find the .fla here:

https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B3L2bumwc4onRGhLcGNId1p2Szg/edit
 (If this does not work let me know, it is the first time I used Google Drive to share files)

1 .When I press ctrl+enter I can see it is moving. When I look for the animation, I do not seem to find it. When I select to create a spritesheet, flash suggest creating a spritesheet with one frame in the base pose and no other (animation) frames.

What is causing this and how do I correct it?

2 .I want to convert it to a sprite sheet for 32 angles of movement. Is there any magical easy way to get this done? Is there a workaround without using Flash CS6 to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with flash but not with CS6 version. With the version that I've worked is CS, but from the description I can tell you the following:

1) If you press Ctrl-Enter and you see the animationm then in the stage you have a MovieClip. If you double click on it, you will see the timeline.

2) Probably Flash need all the frames to generate a spritesheet, you can do the following: enter in the movieclip, select all the frames, right click "Copy frames", then go back to the stage, select a frame in the timeline, then right-click "Paste frames". This sould put all the movieclips frames on the stage, and Flash will "see" all the frames.

3) Or you can transform the movieclip into "Graphic", and select the option "Play until the end"(?? I don't remember the right text, sorry), and in the timeline add many frames as the total length of the movieclip. You have to be able to see the animation, and I'm pretty sure that Flash will can export an spritesheet.

Let me know if you were success.

PS: Sorry if I have many grammar errors. I wrote this very fast for my knowledge of english, :P

Comment: Grammar is fine. I understand you perfectly.